# How to move data based on index to different tables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code to get tables depends on how many items are selected in the left window in my image below but don't know What I need to write in the `onClick` function of the button to move the first selected item to the first table `GMV1` and the second selected item to `GMV2` and so on.

What I want to do is first check the status of `contractLineItemSelectionChecked`. If the status is true, check the selected items have different contract ids and push the different contract id objects to different places.

```
[
  {
    cNo: "CDH0000403",
    contractLineItemSelectionChecked: true,
    companyCode: "1360",
    profitCenter: "DHA1",
    approverId: "C7937"
  },
  {
    cNo: "CDH0000404",
    contractLineItemSelectionChecked: false,
    companyCode: "1360",
    profitCenter: "DHA1",
    approverId: "C7937"
  },
  {
    cNo: "CDH0000405",
    contractLineItemSelectionChecked: true,
    companyCode: "1360",
    profitCenter: "DHA1",
    approverId: "C7937"
  }
];
```

```
<Field
  name="transactionSelected"
  component="select"
  className="custom-select my-1 mr-sm-2"
  id="moveContractLineItems"
  onChange={e => {
    setFieldValue("transactionSelected", "GMV+ /contract");
    document.getElementById("creategoodsMovementsContractsTransaction").click();
    getIndex();
  }}
>
  <option key="select" value="">
    Select
  </option>
  <option key="GMV+ /contract" value="GMV+ /contract">
    GMV+ /contract
  </option>
  <option key="PMT+/contract" value="PMT+/contract">
    PMT+/Contract
  </option>
</Field>;
```

```
<FieldArray name={`transactions["goodsMovements"].transactionItems`}>
  {({ push }) => (
    <input
      type="button"
      hidden
      id="creategoodsMovementsContractsTransaction"
      onClick={() => {
        let myCounter = 0;
        checkedCheckboxes.forEach(v =>
          v.contractLineItemSelectionChecked ? myCounter++ : v
        );
        for (var i = 0; i < myCounter; i++) {
          push({
            name:
              "GMV" +
              (typeof values.transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems !==
                "undefined" &&
                values.transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems.length + 1),
            transactionId: "",
            transactionType: "1",
            requestedPostingDate: null,
            companyCode: "",
            profitCenter: "",
            attachments: [],
            comments: "",
            transactionLineItems: []
          });
        }
      }}
    />
  )}
</FieldArray>;
```

```
<button
  type="button"
  className="btn btn-primary my-1"
  onClick={() => moveItems()}
>
  Move
</button>;
```

[image: Here is the image what I'm getting]

Comment: I don't think anyone understands your question. What is a `contract id` and what is `selected item` and where do they need to be pushed to? Maybe you can better phrase the question as I have this data and needs to be converted to this expected output based on these rules, preferably your rules use the same names as properties of your data.

Comment: `contact id` is the unique parameter of an array object , In that attached image we can select the items those are `selected items` , if we select 2 items from the left side table  as shown it will create 2 tables and the first contract number object should go to `gmv1` table and second contract object goes to `GMV2` and so on

Comment: So you have a list of items called contracts and every item has a select box. If the select box is checked then a second list will show all the items where the select box is checked?

Comment: yes,how many items we will select that many tables will create automatically  and we need to push each row to different tables

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following will give you an idea how to do this:

```js
const Item = React.memo(
  //use React.memo to create pure component
  function Item({ item, onChange, checked }) {
    console.log('rendering:', item.id)
    // can you gues why prop={new reference} is not a problem here
    //  this won't re render if props didn't
    //  change because it's a pure component
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{item.name}</div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          checked={checked}
          onChange={() => onChange(item.id, !checked)}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
)
const SelectedItem = React.memo(
  //use React.memo to create pure component
  function SelectedItem({ item }) {
    console.log('rendering selected:', item.id)
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{item.name}</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
)

class Parent extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    data: [
      { id: 1, name: 'one' },
      { id: 2, name: 'two' }
    ],
    checked: {}
  }
  toggle = (_id, add) => {
    const newChecked = add
      ? {
          ...this.state.checked,
          [_id]: true
        }
      : // cannot use Object.fromEntries because SO babel is too old
        Object.entries(this.state.checked)
          .filter(([key]) => Number(key) !== _id)
          .reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
            result[key] = value
            return result
          }, {})
    this.setState({ checked: newChecked })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h4>items</h4>
          {this.state.data.map(item => (
            <Item
              item={item}
              onChange={this.toggle}
              checked={Boolean(this.state.checked[item.id])}
              key={item.id}
            />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div>
          <h4>Selected items</h4>
          {this.state.data
            .filter(item => this.state.checked[item.id])
            .map(item => (
              <SelectedItem item={item} key={item.id} />
            ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

//render app
ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```